# Multiple joins statements / multiple table query

Tags: sql, inner-join, insert-into

Apologies if the pseudo idea is a little confusing.

Basically I have 3 tables, the tables do not have an exact match on an attribute.

I need to compare whether any of values 2-5 from table 1 either match any value from table 2 on a certain attribute

OR

whether any of values 2-5 from table 1 either match table 3 on a certain attribute

If there is match, they will then be inserted into the newtable.

When I run either Inner join without the other, I seem to receive the filtered results I wanted from either statement. When I add them together, I don't get the correct results.

Is there any way to combine to inner joins or use any other sort of syntax/command to make this comparative search/insert?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

```
INSERT
INTO newtable
(
 attribute1new
 attribute2new
 attribute3new
 attribute4new
 attribute5new
 attribute6new
)
SELECT
    t1.attribute1,
    t1.attribute2,
    t1.attribute3,
    t1.attribute4,
    t1.attribute5,
    t1.attribute6
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.attribute2 = table2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute3 = table2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute4 = table2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute5 = table2.attribute9

INNER JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.attribute2 = table3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute3 = table3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute4 = table3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute5 = table3.attribute8
;
```

Comment: If you don't care about performance, how about running each join as a separate query and union it to a single result set? E.g. select * from t1 join t2 on <something> union select * from t1 join t3 on <something else>

Comment: Shouldn't those be left joins and add condition `WHERE T2.ATTRIBUTE9 IS NOT NULL OR T3.ATTRIBUTE8 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to get the expected result:

```
SELECT
    t1.attribute1,
    t1.attribute2,
    t1.attribute3,
    t1.attribute4,
    t1.attribute5,
    t1.attribute6
FROM table1 t1
where exists (select * from table2 t2
where t1.attribute2 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute3 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute4 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute5 = t2.attribute9)

OR

exists (select * from table3 t3
WHERE t1.attribute2 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute3 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute4 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute5 = t3.attribute8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`s or you will only get results that exist in both tables.  Then you need to use `NULL` handling to assure that there is at least one match (in your `WHERE`).  You can do that with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    t1.attribute1,
    t1.attribute2,
    t1.attribute3,
    t1.attribute4,
    t1.attribute5,
    t1.attribute6
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.attribute2 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute3 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute4 = t2.attribute9
OR t1.attribute5 = t2.attribute9

LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.attribute2 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute3 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute4 = t3.attribute8
OR t1.attribute5 = t3.attribute8

WHERE COALESCE(t2.attribute9,t3.attribute8) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: But all those [or] conditional joins will kill the performance big time Unless his server is powered by rocketship.

Comment: @Markov I can't think of a better way to write it, though a redesign suggestion is a good idea.  It's a red flag any time one column has to join to many, especially in multiple seemingly identical tables.

Comment: one way I could think of is having a subquery with a UNIONS inside and then 
select * from b
left join (
select artibute2 from table 2 where atr = 2
UNION
select artibute3 from table 2 where atr = 3
) a on a = b
left join another subQuery
Where a.atr is  not null or ........

Something Like this would work. Ofcourse needs to be tested and compared to original data, but would be a better performance than conditional join.